# downloading and saving all images from given URL to desktop not fully working

Tags: java

I have the below code to extract and save all the images from [here](http://ramp.sdr.co.za/cache/1402NYFW/GoRedForWomen/) to my desktop. 
It's working to some extent i.e it downloads only 15 images and stops there. Not sure why rest of the images are not getting downloaded. The last image saved on my desktop is `1402_NYFW_0300_GoRed_w95_h95_cw95_ch95_thumb.jpg`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;

public class ExtractAllImages {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String webUrl = "http://ramp.sdr.co.za/cache/1402NYFW/GoRedForWomen/";
    URL url = new URL(webUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
    HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
    HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = htmlDoc.getReader(0);
    parser.parse(br, callback, true);

    for (HTMLDocument.Iterator iterator = htmlDoc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A); iterator.isValid(); iterator.next()) {
        AttributeSet attributes = iterator.getAttributes();
        String imgSrc = (String) attributes.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);

        if (imgSrc != null && (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpg") || (imgSrc.endsWith(".png")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpeg")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".bmp")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".ico")))) {
            try {
                downloadImage(webUrl, imgSrc);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void downloadImage(String url, String imgSrc) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        if (!(imgSrc.startsWith("http"))) {
            url = url + imgSrc;
        } else {
            url = imgSrc;
        }
        imgSrc = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String imageFormat = null;
        imageFormat = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String imgPath = null;
        imgPath = "C:/temp/" + imgSrc + "";
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
        if (image != null) {
            File file = new File(imgPath);
            ImageIO.write(image, imageFormat, file);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you mean that it just stops? Not that an exception occurs?

Comment: yes, the program stops execution. No error

Comment: The source page is now unreachable (probably caused by the SO traffic ;)). Anyway, my first guess would be that some of the filenames have upper-case file extensions, so changing the if statement to check for valid source files to: if (imgSrc != null && (imgSrc.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || (imgSrc.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) || etc... would fix that.

Comment: tried that too, but no luck. btw the source page is working now. can you please check if its working on your end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the page is working again and I got to take a closer look. Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

String webUrl = "http://ramp.sdr.co.za/cache/1402NYFW/GoRedForWomen/";
URL url = new URL(webUrl);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
htmlKit.read(br, htmlDoc, 0);

for (HTMLDocument.Iterator iterator = htmlDoc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A); iterator.isValid(); iterator.next()) {
    AttributeSet attributes = iterator.getAttributes();
    String imgSrc = (String) attributes.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);

    System.out.println(imgSrc);
    if (imgSrc != null && (imgSrc.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || (imgSrc.endsWith(".png")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpeg")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".bmp")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".ico")))) {
        try {
            downloadImage(webUrl, imgSrc);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm using HTMLEditorKit's read() method directly instead of using the callback. This seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. You are really a Java guru. Don't know what was the problem with earlier code.

Comment: @ruben Does this still work? It doesn't work for me

Comment: I think it has something to do with the HTML tags the iterator looks over, shouldn't it be looking at IMG tags and their SRC attribute?